# How is heavy cargo secured in military cargo carriers?

Tags: cargo

Some big military cargo carriers carry tanks and other heavy equipment and I am not sure if they have some kind of special locks or tie-downs in the cargo space to manage those heavy loads.

How are these very heavy loads secured?

Comment: You mean tiedowns?

Comment: i guess tiedowns are for the complete aircrafts but do we use the same inside the cargo as well as to tie the tanks etc?

Comment: @NitinG - I've tweaked the question a bit, I hope this retains the flavor of what you were asking, while clarifying it.

Comment: Not always well enough, unfortunately. http://www.ntsb.gov/news/press-releases/Pages/20150714b.aspx

Comment: ^ Accompanying video of the crash: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MB9JDBe4wA

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cargo in a military aircraft are secured in the cargo hold using chains, straps etc. connected to stowage tie-down devices, which go into tie-down rings . The following image shows a M1 Abrams tank secured in C-17 Globemaster III using tie-down devices.

[image: M1 Abrams tiedown]

USAF uses three different types of devices to secure cargo in aircraft, which vary in their load capacity:

- MB-1 tie-down device with 10,000 lb rated capacity.
- MB-2 tie-down device with 25,000 lb rated capacity.
- CGU-1/B tie-down device with 5,000-pound rated capacity

The MB-1 and MB-2 are similar in their form and function, with the only difference being their load capacity.This image shows a close-up of the MB-1 and MB-2 tie-down devices:

[image: C-17 tie-down devices]

"[C-17 Globemaster III no. 5139 stowage tiedown devices](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:C-17_Globemaster_III_no._5139_stowage_tiedown_devices.JPG#/media/File:C-17_Globemaster_III_no._5139_stowage_tiedown_devices.JPG)" by [BrokenSphere](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:BrokenSphere) - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via [Wikimedia Commons](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/).

The hook goes into the tie-down ring, while on the other end, straps or chains (from the cargo) go.

The CGU-1/B is a 20-foot nylon web strap with two metal hooks at both ends. While one hook is stationary, the other hook has a ratchet device and can be moved and tightens the device when it is being used.

[image: CGU-1/B]

Note: Apparently, [Military designation system](http://www.designation-systems.net/usmilav/asetds/u-c.html#_CGU) refers to MB-1 and MB-2 as CGU-3/E and CGU-4/E respectively.

Comment: In the Abrams picture it looks like one of the chains has a lot of slack. Do you know whats up with that?

Comment: I think what you're looking at is the slack unused length of the chain used in the tie-down. It's wrapped over the taut span above it which is the same chain.

Comment: In other words, they use the same things to tie the equipment down in the plane as they would on a ground based transport. They probably just throw an extra one or two in because a shifting load on a truck is an annoyance while in a plane, a shifting load can be fatal.

Comment: @FreeMan: Load shifts in a truck can be much more than an annoyance, and can even be fatal as well. Here's one: http://wyandottedaily.com/fatal-accident-may-have-been-caused-by-load-shift/

Comment: Load shifts are problematic no matter the mode -- a shifted heavy load on a flatcar can derail a train or worse yet, wipe out a through-bridge structure altogether; shifted loads can also cause stability hazards in marine transportation.